# Unique Goal Starts

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, goal-tracking

Currently pulling data from the Google Analytics API each day (PHP). The dimensions of this data pull include: 
- Date
- Hour
- Minute

Metrics include 
- Sessions
 - Goalxstarts
 - Goalxcompletions (start and completion are for the same goal).

The issue is that when including hour or minute as a dimension, the number of starts appears to include duplicates. For example, if I have 1,000 goalxstarts for a day. When including the hour and minute dimensions in the API call, it might reflect 1,500 goalxstarts.

When running a report in the Google Analytics Web interface (Custom report) with the hour and minute dimension, the goalxstarts metric does not appear to have duplicates.

I should note that goalxcompletions do not duplicate when including the hour and minute dimensions in the API call.

Does anyone know how to retrieve unique goalxstart metrics from the Google Analytics API? Much appreciated...